# Difference Between SP with BEGIN/END and without BEGIN/END

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have found some SP(stored procedure) written as,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[XXX]
(
   -- Parameters
)
BEGIN

--- Actual Work

END
```

and some as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[XXX]
(
   -- Parameters
)


--- Actual Work
```

What makes it difference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference. That is, it's optional.

What matters is the "end of the batch" which is denoted in SQL Server Management Studio by `GO`

Comment: BEGIN / END is optional, you can add them anywhere (without any IF, WHILE blocks...). I suggest do not use them in SP because you can add some test selects after (redundant) END and then alter procedure with them by mistake.

Answer (score 5):

There is no real difference. [Create procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) syntax specifies `BEGIN` and `END` as optional. And it makes sense since `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement cannot be combined with other statements in a single batch.